# Create new JSON depending on value entry using jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have the below JSON

```
{
  "com-abc": {
    "componentName": "com-abc",
    "shortName": "abc",
    "tag": "1234",
    "commitId": "bb59d7c",
    "repository": "com-abc"
  },
  "com-def": {
    "componentName": "com-def",
    "shortName": "def",
    "tag": "5678",
    "commitId": "bb59d7cwfer",
    "repository": "com-def"
  },
  "com-ghi": {
    "componentName": "com-ghi",
    "shortName": "ghi",
    "tag": "91011",
    "commitId": "b55cwfer",
    "repository": "com-ghi"
  },
  "com-jkl": {
    "componentName": "com-jkl",
    "shortName": "jkl",
    "tag": "9107766",
    "commitId": "b55cwfer10f",
    "repository": "com-jkl"
  }
}
```

My query:

In the value , there is parameter "shortName" . I am trying to use jq to create a new json if the '**shortName**' matches a particular value. For example, if i pass **shortName** as **'ghi'** the new json should only contain the below sample. I'm trying to use jq here.

```
{
  "com-ghi": {
    "componentName": "com-ghi",
    "shortName": "ghi",
    "tag": "91011",
    "commitId": "b55cwfer",
    "repository": "com-ghi"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_entries()` to create a key/value pair from the JSON objects and match the `.shortName` field against the string needed and use `from_entries` to convert the key value pair back to actual JSON

```
jq 'to_entries | map( select( .value.shortName == "ghi" ) ) | from_entries'
```

or with providing argument string from command-line using the `--arg` field. With that `sn` becomes the variable that contains the string `ghi`, which can be used inside the filter.

```
jq --arg sn ghi 'to_entries | map( select( .value.shortName == $sn ) ) | from_entries' json
```

See it working for a single string match at [jq-playground](https://jqplay.org/s/0Uo1Jpc7tg)

If you are looking for multiple condition matches, use the boolean `and`/`or` statements inside the filter

```
select( .value.shortName == "ghi" or .value.shortName == "abc" )
```

Or use the regex to exact match the strings inside the `test()`

```
select( .value.shortName | test("^(abc|ghi)$") )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in the case of "ghi":

```
jq --arg sn ghi '
    with_entries(select(.value.shortName == $sn))' input.json
```

Here, `--arg sn ghi` has the effect of setting the jq variable $sn to the JSON string `"ghi"`.